# Setting inter-pod affinity across namespaces in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod with the label `app: jenkins-master` on `jenkins` namespace.

I also want to create an `nginx` deployment.

(for reasons beyond the scope of this question, the `nginx` deployment will reside in a different namespace)

I want these two pods to be (softly) scheduled on the same node so I am using the following pod spec in the deployment manifest

```
spec:
  affinity:
    podAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app
            operator: In
            values:
            - jenkins-master
```

How should I syntactically set the `namespace` value to `jenkins` in the above snipper?

(or even better state that I want this to be applicable across `all` namespaces?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify optional associated list of namespaces

```
spec:
  affinity:
    podAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app
            operator: In
            values:
            - jenkins-master
        namespaces: 
        - namespacename1
        - namespacename2
```

As documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#podaffinityterm-v1-core)

```
namespaces
string array    namespaces specifies which namespaces the labelSelector applies to (matches against); null or empty list means "this pod's namespace"
```